# FPGrowth in spark with confused result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I use FPGrowth   in spark . the input  matrix likes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f88EO.png)

and the result is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQnoN.png)

My doubt is why the item 【**I2 I1 I5**】 not in the result ,it also appears twice

Comment: I'm voting down this question because it's low quality. Please read on [how to ask question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason certain itemsets may not appear may be due to FP Growth's pruning of results that have a support level lower than the minimum support level that you would set.  Try decreasing the minimum support level.